# cat STDIN won't work twice in script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, stdin

I have a script that outputs various information and the text fields of an html form (method POST). When I attempt to cat <&0, it displays properly. However a few lines down, I try to cat <&0 again and nothing is printed. What am I doing wrong?

```
....
cat <&0
echo Content length is $CONTENT_LENGTH
cat <&0 | sed -e 's/&/\n/g' | cut -d'=' -f2

....
```

Comment: Could you explain what your script is actually doing? I mean, why do you want to `cat <&0` in the first place?

Comment: Why do you write `cat <&0` instead of just `cat`?

Comment: `<&0` only duplicates (redundantly and idempotently) the file descriptor, not the data available on that descriptor.

Comment: The purpose is I just want to display the submitted text from a HTML form (POST).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong: this is what we should expect.

The first `cat <&0` consumes the entire contents of standard input because that's what `cat` does: it reads all of its input until the end.

When the second `cat <&0` runs, there is nothing left to consume on standard input: the end of file was already reached previously.

If, in a shell script, you need to make 2 or more passes through your standard input, you have to dump it into a temp file, then process the temporary file as many times as you want.

Securely creating temporary files in `/tmp` and making sure they are correctly disposed of when your script terminates or dies is left as an exercise for you :-)

By the way, the `<&0` is unnecessary and does nothing. Its function is to point standard input to file descriptor 0... which is standard input... which is by definition where standard input already points! You can just make that command `cat` alone instead.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to read from standard input twice, you need to buffer it somehow (most likely, in a temporary file). The first `cat` can be replaced by a call to `tee` which also writes the data to a file, which can be reread by the second call to `cat` (which is not necessary either; `sed` can read from the file directly).

```
tee > input_buffer  # Copy standard input to a file and standard output
echo Content length is $CONTENT_LENGTH
sed -e 's/&/\n/g' input_buffer | cut -d = -f2
```