# How create a temporary file in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, tmp

While running a script, I want to create a temporary file in `/tmp` directory.

After execution of that script, that will be cleaned by that script.

How to do that in shell script?

Answer (score 417, accepted):

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/abc-script.XXXXXX)
: ...
rm "$tmpfile"
```

You can make sure that a file is deleted when the scripts exits (including kills and crashes) by opening a file descriptor to the file and deleting it. The file keeps available (for the script; not really for other processes but `/proc/$PID/fd/$FD` is a work-around) as long as the file descriptor is open. When it gets closed (which the kernel does automatically when the process exits) the filesystem deletes the file.

```
# create temporary file
tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/abc-script.XXXXXX)

# create file descriptor 3 for writing to a temporary file so that
# echo ... >&3 writes to that file
exec 3>"$tmpfile"

# create file descriptor 4 for reading from the same file so that
# the file seek positions for reading and writing can be different
exec 4<"$tmpfile"

# delete temp file; the directory entry is deleted at once; the reference counter
# of the inode is decremented only after the file descriptor has been closed.
# The file content blocks are deallocated (this is the real deletion) when the
# reference counter drops to zero.
rm "$tmpfile"

# your script continues
: ...

# example of writing to file descriptor
echo foo >&3

# your script continues
: ...

# reading from that file descriptor
head -n 1 <&4

# close the file descriptor (done automatically when script exits)
# see section 2.7.6 of the POSIX definition of the Shell Command Language
exec 3>&-
```

Comment: Good answer, elegant solution with the file descriptor in case of a crash +1

Comment: `/proc` - except for systems that don't have it.

Comment: what does the `exec 3> "$tmpfile"` do?  Isn't that only useful if the tmpfile is a stand-alone script?

Comment: @AlexejMagura That command creates the file descriptor which is to be used instead of a (regular) file path in order to solve the problem.

Comment: I want to put the second style into a shell function. Since the process isn't exiting, does that mean I need to close the file descriptor at the end of the function call?

Comment: How do you read from the created FD?

Comment: @eckes You can use `cat <3` or something similar. Remember stdin and stdout just happen to live on 1 and 2, you can move them around to other descriptors easily.

Comment: Can this work against directories, like a directory descriptor?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai You can do `mkdir /tmp/del ; cd /tmp/del ; rmdir /tmp/del; ls -l /proc/self/cwd` but it seems less useful than with files because you cannot store anything in such a directory (except for "deleted files").

Comment: @HaukeLaging what do you mean by store anything except for deleted files. I was wondering why can't you store files in a directory descriptor. Is it the shell, the syscall, or the actual filesystem preventing this?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai In contrast to regular files you cannot delete non-empty directories.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I'm primarily looking for a way to do an atomic directory commit. Being able to use a temporary directory for staging and then performing a `rename` op to atomically commit is cool. But if that temporary directory is guaranteed to be deleted when the process is, then I don't have to worry about external garbage collection.

Comment: " You can use cat <3 or something similar." actually that reads from a file named 3 @dragon788.  Also, `cat <&3` will give `Bad file descriptor`.  I'd appreciate it if you either fix it or remove it; misinformation doesn't much help.

Comment: @HaukeLaging will you update this to show how to read from the file descriptor?  Automatically deleting a file you write to and don't read from isn't much good.

Comment: @DanielFarrell I asked your question separately and [got an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435352).

Comment: Note that the latter technique probably does not work on Cygwin or Mingw, because the Windows semantics for file deletions are different.

Comment: It would be great if the above code could be commented for those of us unfamiliar with file descriptors and this technique.

Comment: @MattSephton The text above the code explains what happens there. Do you want an explanation what file descriptors are? Seems a bit out of scope for this question to me.

Comment: The above text isn't a complete description of the script IMHO. I don't want an explanation of file descriptors, or I'd have asked for that.

Comment: Thanks for the edit && comments!

Answer (score 140):

Use `mktemp` to create a temporary file.  The utility returns the full path of the created file.

```
temp_file=$(mktemp)
```

Or, to create a temporary *directory*:

```
temp_dir=$(mktemp -d)
```

At the end of the script, you may want to delete the temporary file or directory:

```
rm "${temp_file}"
rm -r "${temp_dir}"
```

Note: `mktemp` creates a file in the `/tmp` directory or in the directory given with the `--tmpdir` argument.  See the utility's manual for other options and how to modify its behaviour in other ways.

Comment: You can use `trap "rm -f $temp_file" 0 2 3 15` right after creating the file so that when the script exits or is stopped with `ctrl-C` the file is still removed.

Comment: @wurtel What happens if `EXIT` is the only hook for `trap`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Then the trap doesn't fire if the script is stopped with Ctrl+C. A thing to note is that TRAP doesn't help if you `kill -9 $somepid`. That particular kill signal is insta-death with nothing else happening.

Comment: @dragon788 Have you tried that? You should. `bash -c 'echo $$; trap "echo foo" 0; sleep 5'`

Comment: Trapping `EXIT` is enough.

Comment: For those wondering, the trailing integers in `trap "rm -f $temp_file" 0 2 3 15` are the *signals* [upon which to run the first argument](https://www.shellscript.sh/trap.html). 0: exit shell, 2: Interrupt, 3: Quit, 15: Terminate.

Comment: For those who would prefer to write the symbolic names of the signals, the equivalent is `trap "rm -f $temp_file" EXIT INT QUIT TERM`

Comment: On older systems, `mktemp` **fails without argument** and prints something like `Usage: mktemp [-d] [-q] [-u] template` instead

Answer (score 34):

Some shells have the feature built-in.

### zsh

`zsh`'s `=(...)` form of process substitution uses a temporary file. For instance `=(echo test)` expands to the path of a temporary file that contains `test\n`.

```
$ {cat $file; ls -l /dev/fd/3; echo test2 >&3; cat $file} 3<> ${file::==(echo test)}
test
lrwx------ 1 stephane stephane 64 Jan 30 11:19 /dev/fd/3 -> /tmp/zshMLbER0
test2
```

That file is automatically removed, once the command has finished.

### bash/zsh on Linux.

Here-documents or here-strings in `bash` versions prior to 5.1 and `zsh` are implemented as deleted temporary files (as was the case in the Bourne shell which introduced here-documents in the late 70s).

So if you do:

```
exec 3<<< test
```

The file descriptor 3 is connected to a deleted temporary file that contains `test\n`.

You can get its content with:

```
cat <&3
```

If on Linux, you can also read or write to that file via `/dev/fd/3`, though with bash version 5.0, you'd first to need to restore write permissions to it (which bash explicitly removes in that version):

```
$ exec 3<<< test
$ cat <&3
test
$ chmod u+w /dev/fd/3 # only needed in bash 5.0
$ echo foo > /dev/fd/3
$ cat /dev/fd/3
foo
```

(some other shells use pipes, or may use `/dev/null` if the here doc is empty).

### POSIX

There is no `mktemp` POSIX utility. POSIX however specifies a [`mkstemp(template)` C API](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkstemp.html), and the `m4` standard utility exposes that API with the `mkstemp()` m4 function by the same name.

`mkstemp()` gives you a file name with a random part that was guaranteed not to exist at the time the function was called. It does create the file with permissions 0600 in a race-free way.

So, you could do:

```
tmpfile=$(
  echo 'mkstemp(template)' |
    m4 -D template="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/baseXXXXXX"
) || exit
```

Note however that you need to handle the clean-up upon exit, though if you only need to write and read the file a fixed number of times, you could open it and delete it just after creating like for the here-doc/here-string approach above:

```
tmpfile=$(
  echo 'mkstemp(template)' |
    m4 -D template="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/baseXXXXXX"
) || exit

# open once for writing, twice for reading:
exec 3> "$tempfile" 4< "$tempfile" 5< "$tempfile"

rm -f -- "$tmpfile"

cmd >&3   # store something in the temp file
exec 3>&- # fd no longer needed

# read the content twice:
cat <&4
cat <&5
```

You could open the file for reading once, and rewind in between two reads, however there's no POSIX utility that can do that rewinding (`lseek()`), so you can't do it portably in a POSIX script (`zsh` (`sysseek` builtin) and `ksh93` (`<#((...))` operator) can do it though).

Comment: Bash also has process substitution using `<()`

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus, yes, but that doesn't use temporary files so is irrelevant here. Process substitution was introduced by ksh, copied by bash and zsh, and zsh extended it with a 3rd form: `=(...)`.

Answer (score 20):

If you're on system which has [mktemp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp), you should use it as other answers.

With POSIX toolchest:

```
umask 0177
tmpfile=/tmp/"$0"."$$"."$(awk 'BEGIN {srand();printf "%d\n", rand() * 10^10}')"
trap 'rm -f -- "$tmpfile"' INT TERM HUP EXIT
: > "$tmpfile"
```

Comment: What happens if `EXIT` is the only hook for `trap`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging: `tmpfile` still be removed before script exit, but not when script received other signals.

Comment: That's not what happens here (GNU bash, Version 4.2.53).

Comment: @HaukeLaging: What do you mean `That's not what happens`?

Comment: The EXIT trap is triggered in any case. May differe from shell to shell, though.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Yes, of course. I mean when you specify other signal, i.e `INT`, `tmpfile` will be removed immediately when you press `Ctrl+C`, not when script exit.

Comment: `mktemp` originated in HP/UX with a different syntax. Todd C. Miller created a different one for OpenBSD in the mid-90s (copied by FreeBSD and NetBSD) and later made it also available as a standalone utility (www.mktemp.org). That's the one that was typically used on Linux until a (mostly compatible) `mktemp` utility was added to the GNU coreutils in 2007. Just to say one cannot really say `mktemp` is a GNU utility.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks for this information, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a little bit improved answer in the line of Hauke Laging's:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile=$(mktemp)  # Create a temporal file in the default temporal folder of the system

# Lets do some magic for the tmpfile to be removed when this script ends, even if it crashes
exec {FD_W}>"$tmpfile"  # Create file descriptor for writing, using first number available
exec {FD_R}<"$tmpfile"  # Create file descriptor for reading, using first number available
rm "$tmpfile"  # Delete the file, but file descriptors keep available for this script

# Now it is possible to work with the temporal file
echo foo >&$FD_W
echo bar >&$FD_W  # Note that file descriptor always concatenates, not overwrites

cat <&$FD_R
```

Comment: It should be noted that the content is available only once. I.e. if I do cat <&$FD_R for the second time, no output is produced. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166482/cat-stdin-wont-work-twice-in-script/166485. 

Is there any way to have the file automatically deleted if the program crashes, but making it accessible multiple times?

Comment: @smihael You can simply create a second ```exec {FD_R2}<"$tmpfile" ``` before the call to ```rm "$tmpfile"``` Then, to read it first time, use ```cat <&$FD_R```. And, to read it the second time, use ```cat <&$FD_R2```. To generalize, if you need to read it n times, you can create n read file descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

My workflow typically with temp files is because of some bash script I'm testing.  I want to `tee` it up so I can see that it's working and save the output for the 
next iteration of my process.  I've created a file called `tmp`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(mktemp /tmp/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%T_XXXXXX"))
```

so that I can use it like

```
$ some_command --with --lots --of --stuff | tee $(tmp)
```

The reason I like the datetime formatted before the random values is it allows me to find the tmp file that I just made easily, and I don't have to think about what to name it next time (and focus on just getting my dang script to work).

Answer (score 1):

If you want your solution to work with a pure POSIX shell, it's a little tricky, because POSIX doesn't have a `mktemp`. See [Why is there no mktemp command in POSIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614808/why-is-there-no-mktemp-command-in-posix) for more information.

However, here is a work-around solution for POSIX shell that doesn't require `m4` and implements at least basic `mktemp` as well as the `-d`/`--directory` option to create temporary folders as well:

```
#!/bin/sh
mktemp() (
    create=f
    for option; do
        case $option in
            -d|--directory) create=d;;
            *) printf %s\\n "$0: unknown option '$option'" >&2; exit 1;;
        esac
    done
    set -o noclobber
    exec 2>/dev/null
    while :; do
        tmpname="$TMPDIR/tmp.$(</dev/urandom tr -dc "[:alnum:]" | dd bs=1 count=10 2>/dev/null)"
        case $create in
            f) umask 0177; printf "" >"$tmpname";;
            d) umask 0077; mkdir "$tmpname";;
        esac && break
    done
    printf %s\\n "$tmpname"
)
```

Of course, it would be possible to further extend this function with option parsing via `getopts`, for example, to add support for templates etc.

Comment: POSIX does not define `$TMPDIR`.

Comment: @Dr.KoutheirAttouchi https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03  "TMPDIR This variable shall represent a pathname of a directory made available for programs that need a place to create temporary files."