# POSIX (or portable) way to forward emails from crontab

Tags: shell, cron, posix

I've got an installer/updater script that's meant for IRIX/Linux/macOS/FreeBSD and I would like to extend its compatibility to Solaris.

I've already fixed a few parts that weren't POSIX compliant, except for the `crontab` which is generated like this:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' MAILTO=me@xyz.org '*/15 * * * * /path/cmd' | crontab -
```

```bsh
# crontab -l # (on Linux/macOS/FreeBSD)
MAILTO=me@xyz.org
*/15 * * * * /path/cmd
```

<sup>**note:** `/path/cmd` is quiet unless it detects a problem</sup>

The code fails on Solaris for three reasons:

1. `MAILTO=` throws a syntax error
2. `*/15` throws a syntax error
3. `crontab -` tries to open the file named `-`

I fixed **#2** and **#3** with:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' '0,15,30,45 * * * * /path/cmd' | crontab
```

```bsh
# crontab -l
0,15,30,45 * * * * /path/cmd
```

Now I don't know how to convert the `MAILTO=` part. What would be a POSIX way to forward emails from a `crontab`?

---

###### Selected workaround:

Thanks to *@ilkkachu* and *@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'* pointers, here's how I decided to **emulate** crontab's `MAILTO` behavior in a POSIX compliant way:

```bsh
# crontab -l
0,15,30,45 * * * * out=$(/path/cmd 2>&1); [ -n "$out" ] && printf \%s\\n "$out" | mailx -s "Cron <$LOGNAME@$(uname -n)>" me@xyz.org
```

But, there's a potential problem with this solution: if `printf` is **not** a shell builtin **and** the output is too big then it will fail with an `Argument list too long` or the likes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `MAILTO` is no good for a software installer even where it's supported, because it's a global setting: it would apply to all the entries in the crontab, not just to the one added by your software.

If you want your software to send emails to a different address, you need to handle that in your own code. And that means you need to handle the logic of exit status and empty output yourself.

Here's some untested code that implements this logic. Replace newlines by spaces (or just remove them) to put them on a single line in the crontab file.

```
out=$(mktemp) &&
/path/cmd >"$out" 2>&1;
status=$?;
if [ "$status" -ne 0 ] || [ -s "$out" ]; then
  mailx -s "/path/cmd exited with status $status" me@example.org <"$out";
fi;
rm -- "$out";
```

This code uses only POSIX features plus the widely available [`mktemp`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mktemp&sektion=1). Unfortunately, it's not available on IRIX. If IRIX has a POSIX-compliant m4, [you can use it to implement `mktemp`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181996). As a fallback, you can store a temporary file somewhere under the user's home directory, or in some other directory where only the other may write. Do not create a temporary file with a predictable name in a shared directory like `/tmp`: [that's insecure](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/378.html).

Comment: @ilkkachu I wanted to avoid running the command if the temporary file couldn't be created. But I hadn't paid attention to the fact that it would also result in not sending an email or removing the temporary file if the command fails.